# is angular guard a secure way to protect an application from unauthorized actions?

Tags: angular, api, security, authorization

**the simplified business case**

say we are building a product application, each admin will be given access to specific products from the super admin, admins can't access/modify/delete other products than these

**the proposed solution**

in the backend: there is one API that takes product id with the JWT and return whether this admin has access to this product or not

in the frontend (Angular): will call this API whenever the user try to access any component regarding the product, and depending on the API response will give the user access or redirect to homepage otherwise

**current route code**

```
{
    path: 'product/:id',
    component: ProductComponent,
    canActivate: [ProductGuard],
}
```

**current guard code**

```
export class ProductGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    protected productService: ProductService,
    protected router: Router,
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.productService.getProduct(next.params.id).pipe(
      map(product => {
        if (!product.hasAccess) {
          return this.router.createUrlTree(['']);
        }
        return true;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return of(this.router.createUrlTree(['']));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**my question**

is this solution a secure way to protect our products? if not what is the secure approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**No** there is no way a guard within your frontend will ever be a secure method. It is a concern of your backend to secure any non public endpoint. It is easily possible to bypass any guard within your browsers dev tools.

Comment: You need to secure your endpoints by validation of the users JWT (which obviously gets send within the requests header). Some resources: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: An additional note on this. Dont try to implement it yourself, the framework (backend) you are using may already have the tools you need. Try searching for them.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using Guards is to limit access to your application routes/components, so you still have to secure your backend acting like there is no security validation in the frontend or there is no frontend and anyone can access your endpoints directly.

In your case, the admin already authenticated to use the system but doesn't have permission to access/modify/delete

1. Access -  In this case, if you are using JWT , you can add the type of user `admin` then simply inside your Guard check if the current user of type `admin` then decide whatever you want to do
2. Modify/Create - In this case, if you have routes for  Modify/Create component so you should do the same as point #1, if they are just buttons ( popup components ) in your component/menu, you can create a custom directive to check if the user has permission to access these buttons or not and based on that you can show/hide these buttons